# How to get separate alerts for different monitored regions on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, mkmapview, core-location

I am trying to create different alerts when entering 5 different regions. I'm currently setting up the regions like this...

```
//Monitoring a Region
        CLLocationCoordinate2D layerCoords =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.385909, -6.260067);
        CLRegion *layerRoom = [[CLRegion alloc]
                initCircularRegionWithCenter:layerCoords
                                      radius:100
                                identifier:@"layerRoom"];

        // Start monitoring for our CLRegion using best accuracy
        [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:layerRoom
                    desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

and I can easily just set up 5 more but for alerts I'm not quite sure what to do. I'm currently using this method...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    UIAlertView *locationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"You have arrived!"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];


    // Display the alert
    [locationAlert show];

}
```

And I don't know how to customize it for each region. Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm a complete beginner. Can anybody help? Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didEnterRegion gives you a region parameter. You can use that to check if it's the roomRegion or some other region. Keep them around in an array or dictionary or whatever so you can compare them to the region you have entered.

Comment: Do you mean something like,  if ([region containsCoordinate: layerCoords] == YES) {do something} ?

Comment: Well my first attempt would have been more like  if(region == layerRoom) {do something} but that would depend on you keeping a reference to layerRoom and iOS returning a reference to the region that has been triggered rather than a fresh one that has the same boundaries. So long as your regions don't over lap your approach looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Craig! I tried if(region == layerRoom) but it doesn't recognize layerRoom. Probably because I set up region monitoring in the - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil method. while the alert occurs in the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region method. I tried taking the region monitoring out of the methods but that causes problems too. Not sure where I should be putting it?

Comment: If you're going to use layerRoom in two functions you can't expect to declare it in one and the other know about it. Variable scope (as in which other functions know about the variable) is something that you should have covered already if you're dealing with iOS. Take a look at your MKMapView, that variable is available to all your functions because it is declared in the header not within just one function. I think we're getting off topic. For now try your idea with the containsCoordinate and then look into "scope".

Comment: OK. Thanks, @Craig. Really appreciate your help. I've had to learn all this in a few weeks on my own for a thesis project we're doing at school, which is why my basics aren't too strong.

Comment: Hi again @Craig. Thanks so much for your patience. So if(region==layerRoom){do something} works if I declare and assign values to layerRoom again within the didEnterREgion method. I understand about declaring layerRoom in my .h file will make it a global variable but where do I assign the values in the .m file? Cos' it says that I'm hiding the variable if I assign it in any of the methods.

Comment: unless I create a new class and put everything in there?

Comment: If it says you are hiding the variable you must be redeclaring one in the function instead of using the one you have declared for a class. Once you've declared (CLRegion *layerRoom;) your layerRoom, you must initialize it (layerRoom = [[CLRegion alloc].......) and then you can use it (if(layerRoom==region)). You only need to declare and initialize once, and make sure there is no way the code can try to use it until both those steps are complete.

Comment: Got it! Yay! It works! Thank you, thank you a million times! @Craig

Comment: Just in case people use this as a reference, if (region == namedregion) doesn't work. Something to do with shared resources and not being able to do pointer-level comparisons I think. but if([region containsCoordinates:yourCoordinates]) works.